# Create Google Analytics 4 Property using API

Tags: google-analytics, google-api

I am looking for a way to create GA4 property using the API.

I tried to use this:

```
async function createGoogleAnalyticsProperty(domain, accountId) {
    const analytics = google.analytics({
        version: 'v3',
        auth: jwtClient
    });
    const property = await analytics.management.webproperties.insert({
        accountId,
        resource: {
            websiteUrl: `https://www.${domain}`, // Replace with the actual domain
            name: domain,
            websiteIndustryCategory: 'UNSPECIFIED', // Adjust as needed
        },
    });
    return property.data;
}
```

However, it seems that this creates UA analytics property instead.

I went trough the docs, but I cannot find anything on how to create GA4 property using the API

**EDIT:**

Found this, but seems like it's not available yet: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/admin/v1

What to do ?

UA analytics is not supported anymore, seems like we're currently without an API for this ?